# assign style with *ngIf evaluation in angular2

Tags: css, angular

This is what I have:

**home.html**

```
<li *ngFor="let item of myList">
        <div *ngIf="item.messageText === {{myVar}}" class="bordered">{{item.messageText}}</div>
        <div *ngIf="item.messageText !== {{myVar}}" class="greyedOut">{{item.messageText}}</div>
</li>
```

in **home.ts** I have defined the variable `myVar` and I've assigned to it a value.

I want to assign bordered class to the element of myList which has a value equal to `myVar` and assign another class if that element's value is different.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`*ngIf` would work if you change `{{myVar}}` to `myVar`(without interpolation) in expression.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of myList">
    <div *ngIf="item.messageText === myVar" class="bordered">{{item.messageText}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="item.messageText !== myVar" class="greyedOut">{{item.messageText}}</div>
</li>
```

---

Though I would prefer you to use `ngClass` here, more cleaner and better solution.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of myList">
    <div [ngClass]="item.messageText == item.messageText ? 'bordered': 'greyedOut'">
      {{item.messageText}}
    </div>
</li>
```

**OR**

```
<li *ngFor="let item of myList">
    <div [ngClass]="{'bordered': item.messageText == item.messageText, 'greyedOut': item.messageText !== item.messageText }">
      {{item.messageText}}
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Per convention we would write `greyed-out` instead of camelcased `greyedOut` for HTML properties and css classes.

Comment: Can you have a class attribute set already but then have a ngClass in addition - where you want to have an additional class but only if it evaluates to true?

Comment: @ user6162768 Yes it is possible. You can define any number of css class for an element.

Comment: i have an *ngFor which renders 6 items. i am performing an image transition when each of the loop div is hovered. is there a way i apply the style to the current div only. cause on hover of one item, the ngClass applys the style to all 6 divs

Comment: @Buchi you can think of using plain CSS in that case.. `div:hover { /* your css here */ }`

Comment: @PankajParkar i found a way using the object id, which can only be unique at everypoint.

Answer (score 7):

To complete Panjak Parkar's answer, and to answer to the question in the title (style)

```
<li *ngFor="let item of myList">
    <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color':item.country === 'UK' ? 'green' : 'red'}">
    </div>
</li>
```